# "connect: Network is unreachable" when trying to ping6 or traceroute6 ipv6.google.com

Tags: debian, networking, amazon-ec2

Good afternoon. I set up an EC2 instance a few months ago and just about now I've gotten around to set up IPv6 on it.

I've followed [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-migrate-ipv6.html) guide from Amazon, however, I can't reach any server using IPv6. I have updated my VPC and subnets, my route table, my security group rules, and I've assigned an IPv6 address to my instance. DHCP seems to be working fine on Debian 11, but nothing. I'll send the output of a few commands.

```
root@ip-172-31-40-213:~# dhclient -6 -v
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.4.1
Copyright 2004-2018 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on Socket/ens5
Sending on   Socket/ens5
PRC: Confirming active lease (INIT-REBOOT).
XMT: Forming Confirm, 0 ms elapsed.
XMT:  X-- IA_NA "`Rll"
XMT:  | X-- Confirm Address 2600:1f1e:8c9:4c00:1a6e:56e3:12dc:d5c2
XMT:  V IA_NA appended.
XMT: Confirm on ens5, interval 1040ms.
RCV: Reply message on ens5 from fe80::8c2:a2ff:fe77:2456.
RCV:  X-- Server ID: 00:03:00:01:0a:c2:a2:77:24:56
message status code Success.
PRC: Bound to lease 00:03:00:01:0a:c2:a2:77:24:56.

root@ip-172-31-40-213:~# ifconfig
ens5: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9001
        inet 172.31.40.213  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 172.31.47.255
        inet6 2600:1f1e:8c9:4c00:1a6e:56e3:12dc:d5c2  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::8aa:60ff:fe52:6c6c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 0a:aa:60:52:6c:6c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3929  bytes 436855 (426.6 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3181  bytes 1140981 (1.0 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 12  bytes 1020 (1020.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 12  bytes 1020 (1020.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.8.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  destination 10.8.0.1
        inet6 fd42:42:42:42::1  prefixlen 112  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::ffd4:c6ee:d499:b590  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 500  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4  bytes 304 (304.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

admin@ip-172-31-40-213:~$ ip neigh show
172.31.32.1 dev ens5 lladdr 0a:c2:a2:77:24:56 REACHABLE
fe80::8c2:a2ff:fe77:2456 dev ens5 lladdr 0a:c2:a2:77:24:56 router STALE

root@ip-172-31-40-213:/etc/network# ifdown ens5 && ifup ens5
Killed old client process
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.4.1
Copyright 2004-2018 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/ens5/0a:aa:60:52:6c:6c
Sending on   LPF/ens5/0a:aa:60:52:6c:6c
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPRELEASE of 172.31.40.213 on ens5 to 172.31.32.1 port 67
Killed old client process
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.4.1
Copyright 2004-2018 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

no link-local IPv6 address for ens5

If you think you have received this message due to a bug rather
than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
process and the information we find helpful for debugging.

exiting.
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.4.1
Copyright 2004-2018 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/ens5/0a:aa:60:52:6c:6c
Sending on   LPF/ens5/0a:aa:60:52:6c:6c
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on ens5 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5
DHCPOFFER of 172.31.40.213 from 172.31.32.1
DHCPREQUEST for 172.31.40.213 on ens5 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
DHCPACK of 172.31.40.213 from 172.31.32.1
bound to 172.31.40.213 -- renewal in 1575 seconds.
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.4.1
Copyright 2004-2018 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on Socket/ens5
Sending on   Socket/ens5
PRC: Confirming active lease (INIT-REBOOT).
```

If anyone needs me to show something else, I'll happily provide it. Thank you!

Some other info that might be of interest:

/run/network/interfaces.d/ens5:

```
auto ens5
allow-hotplug ens5

iface ens5 inet dhcp
iface ens5 inet6 manual
   try_dhcp 1
dns-nameservers 2001:4860:4860::8888 2001:4860:4860::8844
```